# typedef with range clamping

Tags: go

In Go we can say:

```
type Month int
```

to create a new type based off of int.

Is it possible to also say that the range of values allowed for this type is 1 - 12, and to guarantee that no value < 1 or > 12 can be assigned?

Comment: Not at the compiler level, no. You'd have to code the logic yourself wherever it's needed.

Comment: Everything you can do at the language level in Go is described in the spec: https://golang.org/ref/spec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot put limits on an int whether you define it as a custom type or not. The closest you can get is something like the following code using a construct called iota

```
type Month int

const (
    Jan Month = iota + 1
    Feb
    Mar
    Apr
    May
    Jun
    Jul
    Aug
    Sep
    Oct
    Nov
    Dec
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Jan, Feb, Mar)
}
```

This will print `1 2 3`. There are a lot more uses for it, you can look up more information here https://splice.com/blog/iota-elegant-constants-golang/

This does not guarantee that you cannot assign random values to the resulting variable, but as long as you use the defined constants everywhere you should be fine.

Comment: This answer is wrong. The question asked "Is it possible to also say that the range of values allowed for this type is 1 - 12, and to guarantee that no value < 1 or > 12 can be assigned?" Your answer does not guarantee that. Any `int` value is valid: https://play.golang.org/p/h9D2itWVK3M

Comment: The real answer is "no, you cannot do that, but this is the closest you can get to what you want"

Answer (score 2):

You can limit access to a single package by using an unexported variable to store the value. For example,

```
package date

type Month struct {
    month int
}
```

Comment: This limits values to allowed values and zero.  It's not possible to prevent the zero value.